# EC2 instance from AWS command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am very new to AWS.  I've got a Windows instance running and have my aws command line configured. I've read through the AWS docs but can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for.

How do I view my current instances from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

If by view your current instances, you mean list all running instances from the command line, you can call the **describe-instances** command:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances
```

This will list all of your current instances.

See [describe-instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html)

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the answer by Rodrigo M, you should use `describe-instances` to view your EC2 instances.  In general, the `help` command is the best way to explore the CLI.  Start with `aws ec2 help` and try the various options.  You can get more details on subcommands with `aws ec2 describe-instances help` as well.

The output is a bit verbose and by default in JSON.  This can be a bit overwhelming and hard to read without additional processing.  I'd recommend getting familiar with the `--query` aws CLI parameter if you intend to use the CLI interactively.

In particular, I use this for a quick overview of my EC2 instances:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId, Tags[?Key==`Name`] | [0].Value, State.Name, PublicDnsName]' --output table
```

To check one particular attribute on an instance:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query Reservations[0].Instances[0].InstanceType --output text --instance-ids <my-instance-id>
```

The CLI is very powerful once you get comfortable with learning the commands and managing the output.  It's also helpful for learning the porgramming APIs as well, since aws CLI commands generally map one-to-one with an API call.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, will take your advice on board :)